# How to run react port and backend port in different ports?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, tailwind-css

I run a react frontend application. I also serve an API in the backend. When I do "node server.js" it runs at port 5000 and then when I npm start it tries to run at port 5000 but as it is busy, I choose a different one and it goes to 5001.

However, if I use nodemon and concurrently to run both frontend and backend in one command, there is no backlash asking me that the ports are busy. I suspect backend does not run if I do that because I cannot reach it through localhost/api/data link.

How can I run them in different ports? I use craco in start scripts because I use tailwindcss, so cross-env does not work

Comment: You can manually choose a port in both React/BE frameworks. In CRA, just use the PORT=8000 (or something) environment variable

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're using the `create-react-app` boilerplate.

In that scenario you can add a `proxy` field in the `package.json` file to tell the react server to forward requests locally to a separate endpoint.

More on this is available here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

If your backend is running on port `5000` add the following to your `package.json`

```json
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

Once that's done start up the react server and it should do the forwarding on its own irrelevant of cors.

Comment: I do not think you understood the question. Here is the process: I run the server by running "node backend/server.js" It runs on port 5000. Then I go ahead and run frontend react app with "npm start". Here it notifies me that port 5000 is busy and if I want to run the react app in a different port. I say yes and then it is okay. HOWEVER, if I try to run the commands at the same time via nodemon and concurrently, I never get a notification and I cannot reach my backend data through localhost:5000/api/data

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is provide a proxy and a PORT:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=2000 react-scripts start",
...
```

This way the server will start on 2000 an all HTTP calls will be proxied to 5000.